# Cheatsheat of all standard utilities

Tags: gnu, utilities, documentation

On a fresh installation pressing double tab prints `Display all X possibilities? (y or n)`. `X` seems to always be above 1000, on my Arch it's 3003.

So the [do one thing and do it well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well) philosophy. But how do I find the one I need when I need it?

- asking someone seems to work
- 3003 man pages is a little too much to commit to memory
- introductory cheatsheets exists, what about something more comprehensive?

I imagine something like a mindmap on an A1 sheet where each utility is a leaf.

Comment: Isn't it more about what one wants to do, rather than what commands exist? I would say that in many cases a solution is reached by combining utilities rather than using just one

Comment: @roaima *if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail*. A `QBasic` compiler on a `Win95` is turing-complete. But we do use other tools. Reason? Human lifespan is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use all 3003. You need to be able to navigate the basic ~50 to complete most of the tasks related to text processing and file management.

Here's a very comprehensive guide on Linux, its shell and utilities:

[Linux Quick Reference Guide](https://perso.crans.org/%7Eraffo/docs/linux-guide.pdf)

Comment: Ah, `linux` + `concise one-page representation` == 189 pages. That's why "RTFM" is not a valid answer IMHO. Thanks for the link, I'll study it in coming years.

Answer (score 1):

Start with 5 to 7 commands, and the shell.
Then 20 command is more than enough, learn what they can do (not how to use them). How to use them will come later.

Also use the manual: `man -k «keyword»`